# Does Spring 3.x is still legitimately good for new learners in comparison with 4.x and 5.x versions?

Tags: spring

Does Spring 3.x is still legitimately good for new learners in comparison with 4.x and 5.x versions? And does it still covers the most of spring fundamentals? And on high level what one has missed, if he didn't touched the 4.x and 5.x ?

Comment: No. It's obsolete and unmaintained. Why would you learn that instead of the current version anyway?

Comment: @JBNizet Actually even today if you search for some good tutorials on spring, you may end up with the large number of tutorials floating online . And i feel this need that probably every material should have an expiry date. Because beginners mostly care about understanding the fundamentals and there is no flag available to intimate them that what they are going to experience is not valid anymore.

Comment: A good amount of fundamentals still apply. Now don't get me wrong: they're very, very different if nothing else because technology evolved and so did the framework... but lots of what you had back then is still there.
So if your objective is to learn Spring, go for newer versions. If however you need to delve into its inner workings, you'll probably find that what you have today builds on top of what was already available back then.

Comment: @FawwadAli that's why you should always start with the official tutorials, which are usually maintained and kept up to date, rather than random blog articles, especially old ones.

Answer (score 1):

**Does Spring 3.x is still legitimately good for new learners in comparison with 4.x and 5.x versions?**
No, because you would be learning old ways of implementing for example JSR.

Here are some difference between spring 3 and spring 4.

*RestController annotation

*JSR-335 Lambda expressions

*JSR-310 Date-Time value types for Spring data binding and formatting.

*JSR-343 JMS 2.0.

*JSR-338 JPA 2.1.

*JSR-349 Bean Validation 1.1.

*JSR-236 Java EE 7 Enterprise Concurrency support.

*JSR-356 Spring’s WebSocket endpoint mode.

*Configuring and implementing Spring style application using Groovy 2. Also they specify that first class support for the Groovy applications.

*Also spring plans to add the HATEOS (Hypermedia as the Engine of Application State) support for REST APIs.

Also Spring 4 is the minimum requirement for running spring boot applications.

**And does it still covers the most of spring fundamentals?** 
Yes, you can get a great introduction with Spring framework and MVC approach, but that is also covered in spring 5 courses as well.

**And on high level what one has missed, if he didn't touch the 4.x and 5.x ?**
Consider the difference between 3 and 4 on top and to add the difference between spring 4 and 5
*JDK baseline update.

*Core framework revision.

*Core container updates.

*Functional programming with Kotlin.

*Reactive Programming Model.

*Testing improvements.

*Library support.

*Discontinued support.

Comment: How about if i narrow my findings to only these 3 modules ? Whats your opinion on that ?

1) Spring Core
2) Spring MVC
3) Spring Data JPA

Comment: I cannot really answer that because it really depends what you need to learn.
But I think that Hibernate with Spring MVC would be much better than Spring Data, because Spring boot hides most of the things that are happening under the hood which implies that you will not basically learn much with going straight into Spring Data.